# HowTo deal with n'th selector in javascript when resetting table row colors on picking & highlighting

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to reset a table with even, odd rows after having picked a row changed it's color?
jQuery is not an option.

I expected somthing like this to work.

```
.MyTable tr:nth-child(even) {background: gray}
.MyTable tr:nth-child(odd) {background: darkgray}
.bgYellow
{
  background-color:yellow;
} 


    var rows = selectedRow.parentNode.parentNode.rows;
    for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
      rows[i].className = (i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    }
    selectedRow.removeAttribute('class');
    selectedRow.className = 'bgYellow';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nth-child` selectors have more specificity than `.bgYellow`, so even if a row has a class `.bgYellow` it will get its background from one of the `nth-child` selectors.

Just give it more specifity, `tr.bgYellow` is enough: http://jsfiddle.net/Ya4G7/2/

Comment: Very good.. Thanks a lot.
Gotta pay more attention to the specificitcity in the future :)